# Put a DIV class in the middle using css

Tags: html, css

Having some CSS related problem for layout issues.
firstly see this screenshot: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmw69.png]
Here i have used css like this:

```
.image{float:right; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:10px;}
.description{font-size:15px; font-style:italic; padding:10px; color:#5C5C5C; text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #A1A1A1;}
.image, .description{display:block;}
.main-article{clear:both;}
```

but what i want to do is to display description in the middle. Like this: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX2B1.png]
can you tell me the CSS, to position description class `div` in the middle like the second image. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the html?

Comment: Do you have some more html/css we can see?  But looks like you will need to add a margin-top: value to bump the description class down..

Comment: more css added from my html

Answer (score 2):

Basicly it will be :

```
.description, .image {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: seems like a good idea, but it broke the layout, please see here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MdCFN.png

Comment: iF you produced a codepen or jsfiddle in the beginning it would have been possible to make a demo from your code and explain . This is the base, it might need to be tuned and adapted to your html structure. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a wrapper around the description and image and use `display: table`

```
#container { 
    display: table;
}
#container .image, #container .description {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING! This box model is under revision.**

I'd use Flexible Box Model or Flexbox.

Just you must put the follow classes in the parent element:

*p-flexbox* and *flex-hcc*

Where:

1. **p-flexbox** means *parent-flexbox*
2. **flex-hcc** means *flexbox-horizontal-center-center*

And inside the style you have to put these CSS rules:

```
.p-flexbox {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: box;
}
```

And another these CSS rules

```
.flex-hcc {

   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
           box-orient: horizontal;

   -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -moz-box-pack: center;
           box-pack: center;

   -webkit-box-align: center;
      -moz-box-align: center;
           box-align: center;
```

}

Here is a example: http://jsfiddle.net/GnbZD/1/

Cheers,
Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the container around the two items and then set the description to

`top: 50%`

Here's a fiddle of it

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewliu/mS4pB/1/

UPDATE:

I have modified a bit, you can do some kind of hack where you need do have containers and using `margin-top: 50%;` and then another container having `margin-top: -25%;`

http://jsfiddle.net/mS4pB/9/

Comment: You're missing a semicolon in your jsfiddle after `top: 50%`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/mS4pB/6/

Comment: Your second method doesn't even center the div.

Answer (score 0):

Like GCyrillus said:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

will work. However, you aren't defining a width. So what you will do is:

```
.image{ width: 300px; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:10px; }
.description{ width: 600px; font-size: 15px; font-style: italic; padding: 10px; color: #5C5C5C; text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #A1A1A1; }
.image, .description{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Once you change those widths to whatever you need, it will work just fine for you. For good measure, make sure you don't fall victim to the inline-block whitespace bug so either apply:

```
.image { margin-left: -4px; } //It works sometimes for me but I think it isn't cross-browser very well.
```

or don't allow any whitespace between your elements in the HTML like so:

```
<div class="description">
    Lorem Ipsum
</div><div class="image">
    <img />
</div>
```

Also, if you want to support IE7:

```
.image, .description { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; *display: inline; zoom: 1; }  //Some people don't like the hacks and some people don't like supporting old IE ;-)
```